# HTML форма, отправка письма PHP, вывод текста AJAX или как сломать голову

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Добрый день! Нужна ваша помощь, господа.

**Предыстория:**

На сайте имеется форма, нужно сделать так, что бы:

1. Форма отправляла данные в гугл форму (красиво формируя в таблицах).
2. В форме есть поле "e-mail", после отправки, пользователю должно отправляться письмо на почту сообщая о регистрации.
3. Пользователя после регистрации нужно каким-то образом проинформировать, что форма работает а не просто обновляет страницу после нажатия кнопки "отправить".

С первым пунктом я разобрался, в интернете много информации по этому поводу. Форма отправляет данные в таблицы

```
<form class="contact_form form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/bl-bla-bla/formResponse" method="post">
<ul>
    <li><input placeholder="Тема0" type="text" name="entry.82222974"></li>
    <li><input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="mail" name="entry.1824090412"></li>
    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Тема1" name="entry.1638850810"></li>
    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Тема2" name="entry.856932552"></li>
    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Тема3" name="entry.1016239961"></li>
    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Тема4" name="entry.1906109374"></li>
    <li><button class="submit" type="submit"/>Отправить</button></li>
</ul>
    <p class="msgs"></p>
</form>
```

Со вторым пунктом я разобрался тоже [Пользовался этим мануалом](http://smartlanding.biz/forma-obratnoj-svyazi-v-modalnom-okne.html).

По отдельности все работает хорошо, но как только я соединяю все воедино, перестает работать отправка в гугл форму.

Я так понял, не работает она из за этого скрипта, который отвечает за отправку письма и вывод сообщения под формой **Спасибо за регистрацию!** т.к. работает через AJAX и не перезагружает страницу, а отправка данных в гугл таблицу осуществляется именно через перезагрузку страницы.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        // Получение ID формы
        var formID = $(this).attr('id');
        // Добавление решётки к имени ID
        var formNm = $('#' + formID);
        var message = $(formNm).find(".msgs"); // Ищес класс .msgs в текущей форме  и записываем в переменную
        var formTitle = $(formNm).find(".formTitle"); // Ищес класс .formtitle в текущей форме и записываем в переменную
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'sendmail/mail.php',
            data: formNm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              // Вывод сообщения об успешной отправке
              message.html(data);
              formTitle.css("display","none");
              setTimeout(function(){
                //$(formNm).css("display","block");
                $('.formTitle').css("display","block");
                $('.msgs').html('');
                $('input').not(':input[type=submit], :input[type=hidden]').val('');
              }, 3000);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                // Вывод сообщения об ошибке отправки
                message.html(error);
                formTitle.css("display","none");
                // $(formNm).css("display","none");
                setTimeout(function(){
                  //$(formNm).css("display","block");
                  $('.formTitle').css("display","block");
                  $('.msgs').html('');
                  $('input').not(':input[type=submit], :input[type=hidden]').val('');
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Теперь самый главный вопрос, как и что нужно изменить в этом скрипте, что бы и письмо отправлялось, текст выводился а данные записывались в гугл форму? Может быть заменить отправку письма и вывод текста на что-то другое?

Буду очень благодарен вам за ответ, так как уже пол дня ломаю голову.

Comment: Делал что то подобное, но сообщения рассылал goole script в документе.

Answer (score 1):

```
return false;
```

замените на

```
return true;
```

submit вызывается до отправки формы и, если возвращается false, то отправка формы не выполняется и вы останетесь на той же странице (соответственно данные не отправятся на Google Docs).